# Recursive Data Structures in Ext JS + Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, extjs, jackson

I'm designing a simple User address book in Spring MVC and Ext JS 4.1. I have defined my User class in Java to allow references to other Users:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")
public class User {

    @JsonProperty
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty
    private String email;

    @JsonProperty
    private List<User> friends = new ArrayList<User>();
}
```

I've made use of [@JsonIdentityInfo](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureObjectIdentity) to ensure cyclic references are handled correctly by Jackson for converting into JSON and passing between Ext JS and Spring. I send my JSON like this:

```
{"data":[
    {"@id":1,"name":"John","email":"john@email.com",
        "friends":[
            {"@id":2,"name":"Peter","email":"peter@email.com","friends":[1]}
        ]},
    2],
"total":2,
"success":true}
```

Here John has @id 1 and Peter has @id 2. Peter is defined a friend of John and vice versa. That 2 before the `"total"` is a reference to Peter, since he has already been defined. My question is: now that I've got recursive data structures working from Jackson, how do you integrate them with Ext JS? I have this in `models/User.js`

```
Ext.define('AM.model.User', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields : [ '@id', 'name', 'email' ],
    idProperty : '@id',
    hasMany : [ {
        model : 'AM.model.User',
        name : 'friends',
        associationKey:'friends'
    } ]
});
```

I can read John fine and I can read Peter in john.friends, but I can't read Peter from `data` since all Ext JS is given is `2` (Peter's `@id`). I'm displaying them in a [ExtJS.grid.Panel](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel) and only John is showing up. Peter's row is just blank.

[image]

Do I need to override the Reader and Writer in my [ExtJS.data.Store](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store)?

Comment: Ive noticed that i have essentially the same issue that you, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540001/recursive-tree-menu-structure-in-ext-js-4-1 have you found a good solution for this? Thanks!

Comment: haha, for now no. I've decided not to use associations until I've figured out how they work.

Comment: lol, looks that ill need to figure it out by myself being a newbie on extJS :P. Ill need this on the short term on job, so i will let you know when ive this ready :)

Comment: Yeah ok, I'm in the same boat, I'll let you know if I come up with anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSOG Library: https://github.com/jsog/jsog
JSOG JACKSON Module: https://github.com/jsog/jsog-jackson

you can do that with JSOG library + jackson JSOG module.
Create a custom reader like:

```
Ext.define('Ext.data.reader.Jsog', {
extend: 'Ext.data.reader.Json',
alternateClassName: 'Ext.data.JsogReader',
alias : 'reader.jsog',

getResponseData: function(response) {
    var data, error;
    try {
        data = JSOG.decode(Ext.decode(response.responseText));
        return this.readRecords(data);
    } catch (ex) {
        error = new Ext.data.ResultSet({
            total  : 0,
            count  : 0,
            records: [],
            success: false,
            message: ex.message
        });

        this.fireEvent('exception', this, response, error);

        Ext.Logger.warn('Unable to parse the JSON returned by the server');

        return error;
    }
}});
```

and the store definition like

```
  var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        proxy: {
                        type: 'ajax',
                        reader: 'jsog',
                        url: 'dummydata/data-grid.js'
        },fields: [
            { name: 'company' },
            { name: 'price', type: 'float' },
            { name: 'change', type: 'float' },
            { name: 'pctChange', type: 'float' },
            { name: 'lastChange', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'n/j h:ia' }
        ]
    });
```

and the reader inflate you ref. This solution we implemented.

The dummydata

```
[
{ "@id": "1",  "company" : "a" , "price" : 2},
{ "@id": "2",  'company' : "b" },
{ "@id": "3",  "company" : "c" },
{ "@id": "4",  "company" : "d" },
{ '@ref': "1" },
{ "@ref": "3" },
{ "@ref": "2" },
{ "@ref": "4" }]
```

Comment: Cheers for that, I haven't done Ext JS since writing this last year but hopefully it'll be useful for someone